# Apply Bootstrap & Flat UI on a div or copy all styles to use on the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I built my navbar using Bootstrap with Flat UI on top of it.

Now if I add bootstrap+flat ui into this other html+css file that I have, the hexagons get spoilt.
Basically, my navbar does not work without flat ui and bootstrap while my hexagon page does not work with flat ui and bootstrap so I have no idea what to do! Please help.

navbar code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" /></a> -->
    </div>
    <!-- All the nav link -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="hexagons.html">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="getStarted.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Buy now<i class="fa fa-user-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- navbar collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</nav>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/an732001/pen/NREJwg) is the codepen

Comment: I have seen your code, actually font and line-height properties (in  h1, p and a tags) of CSS are reflating on your code. you have to overweight them by adding these properties in your code. Also you will have to give proper sequence to the css files. At the top 1st position bootstrap, 2nd flat ui and then your custom.css.

Comment: Can I use !important to do so?

Comment: I am unable to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link, I have update your code. [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/guruWork/tn7f952a/1/)

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/guruWork/tn7f952a/1/">jsfiddle</a>
```

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Actually text properties have spoil  your code. You should learn about Typography of bootstrap and flat icon frameworks. So you will get to know about use of it.